# my program doesn't work on an special system

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I wrote an application and it worked on my system fine and there was no problem. I wrote it via visual studio 2012, .net 4.5, C#, and also it uses office 2010. I installed it on several systems and there were no problem with it. but it doesn't work on one of my computers. It installs correct,but I can't open the program. the windows were I wrote the program was 32 bit, and the computer I wanna work with is also 32 bit. the only difference i can see between two systems is that i have .net 4.5.1 on the last computer and the program is written with .net 4.5
i have no other ideas why it doesn't work. any ideas?

This is the problem i receive when i try to run the application:(due to the event name I uninstalled media center and i did the following instruction,but still no change)
Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: CheckPrinter Final.exe

Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0

Problem Signature 03: 5402e7bf

Problem Signature 04: CheckPrinter Final

Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0

Problem Signature 06: 5402e7bf

Problem Signature 07: 7

Problem Signature 08: 32

Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1

Locale ID:    1033

Additional Information 1: 0a9e

Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Additional Information 3: 0a9e

Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: The Problem Has Been SOLVED. I installed .net 4.5 on target computer,but still no change. I looked for .net targeting pack 4.5,but i couldn't fin it.so i installed visual studio 2012 which had .net 4.5 and targeting pack 4.5 . so after installation the problem had been solved. thanks to everyone who left comment on my question. :) (just one more thing: isn't it a blind spot for .net that higher versions don't support lower versions?!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you did every thing right and perfect and detect your problem perfectly too, and should change the .Net framework to an older version. to do that follow this steps:

1. double click on 'Properties' in your solution explorer
2. in 'Application' tab set 'Target Framework' to '.Net Framework 4.5' or any one. but consider the new components that doesn't exist on older version of .Net framework. for example 'System.Threading.Task' does not exist in .Net framework 3.5
3. Compile your project again
4. Enjoy!

Comment: You dont know the error he has and that the target machine has 4.5.1 installed. So your answer doesn't make sense Buddy.

Comment: right,i changed the version of target system to .net to 4.5 and it worked.thanks.

Comment: anytime :) actually newer versions of .Net support older versions, but programs developed by newer version won't execute in older ones

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give more concrete information about your application in order for someone to really help you. For example, apart from the dependencies to the .NET 4.5, what other dependencies does your app have?

Also is your app compiled in x86 (32 bit mode) or in AnyCPU mode?

Maybe your app has a DLL dependency that the problem system does not have the required DLL in the search path or in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache)

To give a more detailed answer we would need more detailed info on the app and the system which is causing the problem

Comment: the program extract a zipfile using zipFile from system.io.compression.FileSystem and then opens the access file and uses the information on tables and at last it prints the data user need. it is wroten in windows 32 bit,but i didn't mention any obligation about it when i was making setup file.the only thing i mentioned in making setup file was .net framework 4.5 or greater

Answer (score 0):

Classical case:

1. Check the Event Log of the PC
2. Build in some debug Events on the Startup Routine
3. Check if the exception handling is implemented in a proper way (No empty catches
   etc.)

Comment: the proplem event name is CLR20r3

Comment: And what is the exact description? You are the developer Buddy, get the exact message, Google for it and get a solution.

Comment: This is the first time I'm developing a software, so I'm not so experienced! I googled for it,but I just found something about media center and I followed the instruction, but there was no change, so I asked my question here!